# Function takes an object with a name property and returns an object

Tags: javascript

The task I have is:

The `makeGuestList` function takes an object with a `name` property whose value will be a string consisting of a first name and a last name, separated by a space. The function should return an object.

The function should remove the `name` property, replace it with `firstName` and `lastName` properties, as shown in the examples below:

```
makeGuestList({ name: "Hannah Fry", age: 46 });
// should return { firstName: "Hannah", lastName: "Fry", age: 46 }
```

My code is thus:

```js
function makeGuestList(person) {
    const [firstName, lastName] = person.name.split(" ");
    return { "firstName": firstName, "lastName": lastName };
}

const guest = { name: "Ada Lovelace" };
console.log(makeGuestList(guest));
```

When I run the code I get the error message:

```
All other properties on the object are unchanged
```

```
✕ AssertionError: expected { firstName: 'Ada', …(1) } to deeply equal { firstName: 'Ada', …(3) }
```

Comment: *"should return { firstName: "Hannah", lastName: "Fry", age: 46 }"* Your code won't return any properties other than `firstName` and `lastName`. So you'd be missing out `age` in that example (and apparently something similar in the different example you're quoting the error from). So you need to do something to either keep those properties when returning the same object (if we read the instructions literally), or add them to a new object you return.

Answer (score 4):

In your current implementation, you’re only returning an object with `firstName` and `lastName`, and all other properties from the original object are not included in the returned object.

To fix this, you can use the spread operator `...` to include all properties from the original object in the returned object.

```js
function makeGuestList(person) {
  const { name, ...rest } = person;
  const [firstName, lastName] = name.split(" ");
  return { firstName, lastName, ...rest };
}
const guest = { name: "Ada Lovelace", age: 36 };
console.log(makeGuestList(guest));
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `...` spread operator, you can also use the `delete` keyword to mutate the original `person` object argument by adding `firstName` and `lastName` property, and then remove `name` property:

```js
function makeGuestList(person) {
  const [firstName, lastName] = person.name.split(' ');
  person.firstName = firstName; // add new property 'firstName' to person
  person.lastName = lastName; // add new property 'lastName' to person 

  delete person.name; // remove `name` property

  return person;
}

const guest = { name: "Ada Lovelace", age: 46 };
console.log(makeGuestList(guest));
```

Comment: FWIW, you can simplify that a bit: `[parent.firstName, parent.lastName] = person.name.split(" "); delete person.name; return person;` Destructuring doesn't only work when you target variables, it works with properties as well.